# How to test fcgi?

Tags: apache-2.4, testing, fcgi

I try to use [foo.pl](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples), but using `/usr/lib/fcgi-bin` as my fcgi directory in the given directive.
I made `foo.pl` executable and after editing my `apache2.conf` I have  restarted `apache2`.
But if I launch my browser and go to `http://localhost/fcgi-bin/foo.pl`, I get a `404`,

> *The requested URL /fcgi-bin/foo.pl was not found on this server.*

This is my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /usr/lib/fcgi-bin/>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        Options +ExecCGI

        # Customize the next two directives for your requirements.
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Following modules are loaded:

```
$ sudo a2query -m
[sudo] Passwort für xXx: 
authz_host (enabled by maintainer script)
proxy_fcgi (enabled by site administrator)
negotiation (enabled by maintainer script)
filter (enabled by maintainer script)
access_compat (enabled by maintainer script)
authz_core (enabled by maintainer script)
deflate (enabled by maintainer script)
authn_file (enabled by maintainer script)
php7.0 (enabled by maintainer script)
authz_user (enabled by maintainer script)
authnz_fcgi (enabled by site administrator)
mime (enabled by maintainer script)
proxy (enabled by site administrator)
mpm_prefork (enabled by site administrator)
dir (enabled by maintainer script)
alias (enabled by maintainer script)
auth_basic (enabled by maintainer script)
setenvif (enabled by maintainer script)
cgi (enabled by site administrator)
env (enabled by maintainer script)
autoindex (enabled by maintainer script)
authn_core (enabled by maintainer script)
status (enabled by maintainer script)
```

Do I haven't see a hint in this example, or what I am missing?

Any answer is appreciate.

Comment: Your apache config would be helpful

Comment: You are right! Please view my edit.